# Inverse of a log and linear function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, inverse-function, lambert-w, elementary-functions

How would you find the inverse of a function that is both linear and logarithmic?

Take this for example:
$f\left(x\right)=ln\left(x\right)+x+1$

Writing it as $y=ln\left(x\right)+x+1$ won't work, at the end after some algebra I get

$e^{\left(y-1\right)} = xe^x$

Is there a mistake in the calculation or is this not the way I am supposed to find the inverse?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: There's no elementary solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for [closed-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) inverses.

A function has an inverse (inverse function) iff it is bijective. Each surjective function can be decomposed into bijective functions (bijective [restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics))) by decomposing its domain. The inverses of the bijective restrictions are the [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Partial_inverses) of the function.

Your function is bijective i.a. for $x>0$.

**1.)**

Let's discuss functions $f\colon D\ \text{non-discrete}\ \subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},z\to f(z)=A(z,\ln(z))$ or $f(z)=A(z,e^z)$, where $A$ is an algebraic function.

These functions are [Elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). The Elementary functions are generated from their complex argument by applying finite numbers of $\exp$, $\ln$ and/or algebraic functions.

**1. a)**

With help of Ritt's theorem on the existence of elementary inverses of elementary functions ([Ritt 1925]), one can deduce that a function $f$ as specified above cannot have elementary partial inverses over non-discrete domains.

**1. b)**

The question of existence of closed-form inverses of functions is different from the question of closed-form solutions of equations. But both questions are interrelated.
Let $F$ an elementary function $D_F\ \text{non-discrete}\ \subseteq\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ and let $\alpha$ a variable that represents an [elementary number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or an algebraic number. If the equation $F(z)=\alpha$ has only a finite number of solutions $z$ that are elementary numbers, the function $F$ cannot have elementary partial inverses over non-discrete domains.

From the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999] follows, that equations $f(z)=\alpha$ ($f$ as specified above, $\alpha$ a variable that represents an algebraic number), where $A$ is a polynomial irreducible over the algebraic numbers, don't have solutions except $0$ that are elementary numbers.

**2.)**

Your function $f$ is not defined for $x=0$, we have to set $x\neq 0$ therefore.

Your result $e^{y-1}=xe^x$ is correct. But consider point 1.) above: the equation cannot have elementary solutions.

But the problem can be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Lambert W is the inverse relation of the function $x\mapsto xe^x$. We have therefore:

$$e^{y-1}=xe^x$$

$$W_k(e^{y-1})=W_k(xe^x)\ \ \ \ (k\in\mathbb{Z}).$$

Now apply the appropriate branches of Lambert W.

$$W_k(e^{y-1})=x$$

Analogous results can be applied also to functions $f$ with $f(x)=a\ln(x)+bx+c$, wherein $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$.
$\ $

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Ritt 1925] Ritt, J. F.: Elementary functions and their inverses. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 27 (1925) (1) 68-90](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1925-027-01/S0002-9947-1925-1501299-9/)